# How to convert a raster image to vector image in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, vector, illustration

I've found some licensed image that I want to reproduce in Inkscape (without backgrounds) but I'm a novice and I would want to get them to make some scientific illustrations.
[image: Earth]
[image: Moon]
Can you show the faster way to get them in inkscape?

Comment: Sometimes you can auto trace images, but it probably won't work well with images like those - especially the top one. Images with gradients don't work well. Probably better to re-create the graphics manually. If you want to try auto tracing, in Inkscape it's located under Path > Trace Bitmap. There are tutorials on youtube on how to use tracing. BTW I wouldn't recommend auto tracing an image from a stock image site. You could be sued for copyright infringement.

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr. As you suggest, I think it is better draw myself the image or buy it.